# Lists and images: Wrong answer - HTML Test

Tags: html, image, list

I just randomly tried this [sample HTML test](https://www.testdome.com/for-developers/solve-question/7299?visibility=129&skillId=3&orderBy=ForDevelopers) and submitted my asnwer.

It shows the error below.

**Lists and images: Wrong answer**

Run the snippet on fiddle and it runs fine.

Really confused and can't really figure out what's wrong in the answer!!!

My answer was this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Company page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Welcome! Here you can find following things:</p>
  <ol>
    <em><li><a href="#logo">Company's logo</a></li></em>
    <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>
  </ol>

  <h1>Company's logo</h1>
  <p>Company uses following logos:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>New logo: <img src="new_logo.gif"></li>
    <li>Old logo: <img src="old_logo.gif"></li>
  </ul>

  <h1>List of employees</h1>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Williams</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions please ?

Thanks

Comment: this seems like homework help or help to pass a job test. you can run the code through an html validator and get the results.

Comment: My suggestion is to go through your code carefully on lines 17 and 18 and you should easily spot the problem.

Comment: I have a suggestion. Take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages, particularly [ask]. before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 1):

I went back through and fixed this code to be in compliance with the W3C validation rules. Here is the code (and it works too):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Company page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Welcome! Here you can find following things:</p>
    
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#logo"><em>Company's logo</em></a></li>
      <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>

    </ol>

    <h1 id="logo">Company's logo</h1>
    
    <p>Company uses following logos:</p>
    
    <ul>
        <li>New logo:<img src="new_logo.gif" alt="newlogopic"/>
        </li>
        
        <li>Old logo:<img src="old_logo.gif" alt="oldlogopic"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
        <h1 id="employees">List of employees</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Williams</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>James</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it can be frustrating looking at something for a while and not figure out what the problem is.  If you run this through the W3C Validator it will give you this error.  [image: Validator error]

To fix this, place the `img` inside the `list element` like so:

```
<ul>
      <li>New logo:<img src="new_logo.gif"></li>
      <li>Old logo:<img src="old_logo.gif"></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT: here is the correct code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Company page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Welcome! Here you can find following things:</p>
    <ol>
      <li><em><a href="#logo">Company's logo</a></em></li>
      <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>
    </ol>

    <h1>Company's logo</h1>
    <p>Company uses following logos:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>New logo:<img src="new_logo.gif"></li>
      <li>Old logo:<img src="old_logo.gif"></li>
    </ul>

    <h1>List of employees</h1>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Williams</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>James</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>


  </body>
</html>
```

You were missing `<tr>` inside your `<tbody>` and `<thead>`.

You should also move `<em>` and `</em>` inside your `<li>` element.

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake to not include my answer in the initial post. I did exactly the same fix and it still says wrong answer!

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on this problem for like 2 hours.... and it turns out the key (for me) was in removing the /li. The funny part is that the line afterwards has not problem with it, but the first one does. I have no idea why, and basically got lucky here.

Also, I'm fairly certain that the img tag is supposed to have an alt="description of picture" , so that is another problem with the code that I don't understand.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Company page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Welcome! Here you can find following things:</p>
    
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#logo"><em>Company's logo</em>
      <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a>
      </li>
    </ol>

    <h1 id="logo">Company's logo</h1>
    
    <p>Company uses following logos:</p>
    
    <ul>
        <li>New logo:<img src="new_logo.gif"/>
        </li>
        
        <li>Old logo:<img src="old_logo.gif"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
        <h1 id="employees">List of employees</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Williams</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>James</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the code I used and it worked:

Answer (score 0):

Lists and Images - There is one em tag,it should be inside the li tag
no other image issue "alt" is for optional but its good practice to add in tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Company page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Welcome! Here you can find the following things:</p>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#logo"><em>Company's logo</em></a></li>
        <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>
      </ol>

    <h1>Company's logo</h1>
    <p>Company uses the following logos:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>New logo:<img src="new_logo.gif"/></li>
        <li>Old logo:<img src="old_logo.gif"/></li>      
      </ul>

    <h1>List of employees</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Williams</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The em should be inside the li and so is the img tag